# Best practices for using Mocks in TDD (MOQ)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tdd, nunit, moq

I am new to using Mocks. But what are it's main purposes? I'm going to start by using Moq to test my application (and NUnit).

For example, I have code that does things like this:

My webpage code behind:

```
public partial class MyWebpage
{
    protected string GetTitle(string myVar)
    {
        return dataLayer.GetTitle(myVar);
    }
}
```

My data access layer:

```
public class DataLayer
{
    public string GetTitle(string myVar)
    {
        // Create the query we want
        string query = "SELECT title FROM MyTable " + 
            "WHERE var = @myVar";

        //ENTER PARAMETERS IN HERE

        // Now return the result to the view
        return this.dataProvider.ExecuteMySelectQuery(
            dr =>
            {
               //DELEGATE DATA READER PASSED IN AND TITLE GETS RETURNED
            },
            query,
            parameters);
    }
}
```

My data provider talks and interacts directly with the db:

```
 public class DataProvider
{
     public T ExecuteMySelectQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getMyResult, string selectQuery, Dictionary parameters)
    {
          //RUNS AND RETURNS THE QUERY
     }
}
```

What's the best way to test all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test the layers separately, you would need to create interfaces for your DataProvider and DataLayer classes that expose the methods that you want to Mock. Then you can use a mocking framework - NSubstitute is very good, less code to write to create the mocks - to mock out the calls to the dependent classes, leaving you to test the code within that specific unit

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
     T ExecuteMySelectQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getMyResult, string selectQuery, Dictionary parameters);
}

public interface IDataLayer
{
    string GetTitle(string myVar);
}

public class DataLayer 
{
    private IDataProvider dataProvider;

    public DataLayer(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Then, in your test code, you create mocks instead of real objects and pass those into the constructor when you instantiate your test objects. To test the DataLayer:

```
[Test]
public void WhenRetievingTitleFromDataStore_ThenDataLayerReturnsTitle() 
{
    var title = "Title";
    var dataProviderMock = new Mock<IDataProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    dataProviderMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteMySelectQuery(<parameters>)).Returns(title);
    var dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProviderMock.Object);
    Assert.That(dataLayer.GetTitle(It.IsAny<string>(), Is.EqualTo(title));
}
```

Comment: yeah i have interfaces for them like you do above (was just cutting down on the code in the post), how would you test your code above?

Comment: Using MOQ, you could create a mock of the IDataProvider interface like this: `Mock<IDataProvider> dataProviderMock = new Mock<IDataProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);` and pass it to the data layer like this: `var dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProviderMock.Object);`

Comment: yeah alright i will test this out. thx. And then I could use the dataLayer object to test that part out, like dataLayer.GetTitle()?

Comment: How is the myVar handled in the mock assert above?

Comment: Is it an input parameter that doesn't affect anything outside of the GetTitle method? If you don't care about the value of it you could use Moq's `It.IsAny<string>()` - will update the test. If you need to pass it through to the ExecuteMySelectQuery method, you can create a constant in the test for that value, and use that to represent the parameter passed in to ExecuteMySelectQuery. You then pass that specific constant value in to GetTitle. If that string is not the same when ExecuteMySelectQuery is called, the mock will fail.

Comment: I really do not see the purpose of that test. The only thing you validate is that a method called with anything returns something. What's the point?

Comment: The purpose is really in the part that I've glossed over. The mocked call to ExecuteMySelectQuery needs specific parameters passed in for the code to execute correctly. This test, whilst admittedly a very contrived example to illustrate a wider point, should be validating that the correct parameters are passed into the called method. It's a bit brittle, but if the values of the parameters passed in are important, the test has value.

Comment: @jgauffin the test verifies that DataLayer collaborates with its DataProvider correctly, and more precisely, that it is able to handle the return value "Title" from the DataProvider.

Comment: The point is that you can't possibly know what the real data provider returns. You just check that it can handle the values that you ***assume*** that the real data layer will return.

Comment: Great point. This is why for each test where a DataProvider mock is set up to return some value (like "Title"), you need another test to prove that the concrete DataProvider is able to return that value in the first place. This might be, as you pointed out, an integration test (exercising against an in-memory DB, for instance). But IMO you need both tests.

Comment: If you have the integration test it's impossible for the unit test to fail, while only having a unit test makes it possible for the application to fail.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not advocating simply using a unit test and mocking the db call. In a real world scenario, the method would probably contain more complex logic which unit tests would add value to. The integration test is required to ensure that the actual db call is executing as expected.

Comment: @jgauffin "If you have the integration test it's impossible for the unit test to fail" => I think you got me wrong. I'm not talking about an end-to-end integration test spanning from MyWebpage to the DB, which would be slow and too coarse-grained IMO. I'm talking about an integration test where the SUT is DataProvider and there's something in the DB that it must return. It's an integration test because DataProvider fetches data from a real database (even if it's an in-memory DB) and the result of the test is subject to errors in the communication with that database - i.e. it is not isolated.

Comment: I'm talking about the test in the answer. If you replace the mock with a real `IDataProvider` you'll get a test which will guarantee that the code works (as long as no one mess with the DB after the test). Mocking `IDataProvider` wont do that.

Comment: Again, this is one approach, but it has drawbacks. If you do that, there are really 3 SUT's in your test (DataLayer, DataProvider and the DB implementation you choose). You won't be able to point at the exact problem if the test fails. The test will be slower and much more fragile/regression prone. It won't reflect the contracts of the objects in play.

Comment: No. you get me wrong. You should of course test the Data Provider separately. But it's in this case implemented in a way that the any class that uses it is also dependent of the database. That also means that any test of the data layer class won't prove anything unless the real DB is used since it's the real DB that controls the returned data types. If you just mock the DB provider (which just is a pass through layer) you have made assumptions on what the real DB will return and there is no guarantee that that assumption is correct. It's false safety.

Comment: If you on the other hand test a class which uses the `DataLayer` class  there is really no reason to use the real DB since the `DataLayer` is a complete abstraction. In that case it's perfectly fine to mock the DL class.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that can go wrong with that is the DB call (the query or the returned result is of wrong data types). That can't be mocked. You need to do integration tests and not unit tests.

Typically you only mock to be able to test logic in the code. You should for instance test so that the data mapper (`this.dataProvider.ExecuteMySelectQuery`) works as defined. but that's of the scope of the code in question.

**Update**

So you got the following classes:

```
public class DataLayer
{
    public string GetTitle(string myVar)
    {
        // Create the query we want
        string query = "SELECT title FROM MyTable " + 
            "WHERE var = @myVar";

        //ENTER PARAMETERS IN HERE

        // Now return the result to the view
        return this.dataProvider.ExecuteMySelectQuery(
            dr =>
            {
               //DELEGATE DATA READER PASSED IN AND TITLE GETS RETURNED
            },
            query,
            parameters);
    }
}

public class DataProvider
{
     public T ExecuteMySelectQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getMyResult, string selectQuery, Dictionary parameters)
    {
          //RUNS AND RETURNS THE QUERY
     }
}
```

If we examine the `ExecuteMySelectQuery` we can see that the `DataLayer` class is dependent of how the types that the database returns since the `DataProvider` just ease the query execution. One could say that it's an addon on top of ADO.NET.

That also means that you can never guarantee that `DataLayer` return what's promised without involving the database. Let's for instance assume that the `table` in the database has a column called `title` but someone managed to use the `int` data type instead.

The things that can go wrong are

- The query is incorrect
- The schema in the database is incorrect (wrong column names, data types etc)
- The mapping

None of those errors can be detected nor tested with the help of a mock.

If you on the other hand use the `DataLayer` clas in another class you can of course mock it. Because the `DataLayer` class itself is a complete abstraction. That means that the callers of the class doesn't have to be aware of anything beneath it. Hence mocking is perfectly fine.

Comment: no. I don't see the point. The code doesn't do anything. The only thing that could go wrong is what I said.

Comment: This is one approach. Others will test every interaction between an object and its dependencies. I guess it all boils down to what you consider is "logic", and consequently worth testing.

Comment: See my comment to your comment on the other answer.